# How do my dotnet 3.1 tools publish working builds without deps.json or runtimeconfig.json

Tags: .net

When I do a self contained publish in my ci container that has the following dotnet --info

```
16:26:12  .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
16:26:12   Version:   3.1.404
16:26:12   Commit:    470f6754b3
16:26:12  
16:26:12  Runtime Environment:
16:26:12   OS Name:     Windows
16:26:12   OS Version:  10.0.17763
16:26:12   OS Platform: Windows
16:26:12   RID:         win10-x64
16:26:12   Base Path:   c:\tools\dotnet\sdk\3.1.404\
16:26:12  
16:26:12  Host (useful for support):
16:26:12    Version: 3.1.10
16:26:12    Commit:  1721e39439
16:26:12  
16:26:12  .NET Core SDKs installed:
16:26:12    3.1.404 [c:\tools\dotnet\sdk]
16:26:12  
16:26:12  .NET Core runtimes installed:
16:26:12    Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.10 [c:\tools\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
16:26:12    Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.10 [c:\tools\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
16:26:12    Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.10
```

I get a working self contained publish build.  But the output files do not include files like *.runtimeconfig.json or *.deps.json.  Are these files not always required/created?  Publishing with .NET 5 tools gives me a non functioning build (troubleshooting is out of scope of this question), with errors related to deps.json.  At first I assumed deps.json was added in NET 5 since I don't have them in my 3.1 output.  But I found this article https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/12/21/netcore-primitives/ from 2017 where he's talking about those files being required even in the core 2.1 sdk.  So clearly the files have been required for a long time.

I publish (with the above environment) using `dotnet publish $Project -o $tempDir -r win-x64 -c Release`
and with further publish settings in the project file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>

    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <PublishSingleFile>false</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>false</PublishReadyToRun>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU</Platforms>
    <ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>false</ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Here is the output of the publish directory (note that I have fudged the app name to "MyApplication" and removed a few irrelevant files for privacy) https://pastebin.com/BHCevmbh

What is going on that I'm getting working builds out of 3.1 sdk without those files?

Update:
I just discovered that if I delete the *.deps.json and *.runtimeconfig.json files from my .NET 5 builds, they start working.  So are these files required?  Everything I've read says they are, yet they do not seem to be...  Why do they exist if they can be deleted and the app still work (or in this case where they are probably misconfigured, the app starts working where it didnt before)?

Comment: How are you publishing things? What is the publish command you are using with each SDK? What does you `publish` directory contain after running the publish command?

Comment: Added these 3 things to the question